# where is String value from Scanner class's .next() method allocated in memory?

Tags: java, memory-management, java.util.scanner

Where is the String value which is taken from user allocated in the memory?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String x = "hello"; // This is stored in String constant pool
String y = "hello";
String z = new String("hello"); // This is stored in normal heap

System.out.println("Enter "+x);
String u = input.next(); // Where is this stored?

System.out.println(x==y) // true because same memory address in SCP
System.out.println(x==z) // false because one is stored in SCP and other in heap
System.out.println(u==x) // false then not in SCP
System.out.println(u==z) // false then not in heap either
```

is the value u stored in Stack then?

Comment: `System.out.println(u==z) // false then not in heap either` what makes you think so? It is still on the heap but not in the SCP.

Comment: Just because two objects are both stored in the heap doesn't make them the same object, which is what == is checking.

Comment: As @Pshemo says, two objects of the same type with the same contents can both be on the heap yet not both be the same object.

Comment: What do you think should be result of `new String("hello") == new String("hello")` and why?

Comment: @Pshemo if the String value of u is in the heap the why did u==z return false?

Comment: @RedwanHossainArnob It's not true that "the String value of u is in the heap".  There is a String object in the heap that is pointed to by the variable `u`.  That object has a value.  There is a **different** String object in the heap that is pointed to by the variable `z`.  It has the same value as the object identified by `u`, but they're _not the same object_.  The equality operator (`==`) compares object **identity**, not object **contents**.  This is why we use `.equals()` to compare objects when we care about their values being equal.

Comment: @RedwanHossainArnob Let me ask counterquestion, why do you think it should return `true`?

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the Scanner class in [OpenJdk8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java), and found that the string is stored within Scanner class as a CharBuffer.

```
public final class Scanner implements Iterator<String>, Closeable {

    // Internal buffer used to hold input
    private CharBuffer buf;
......
}
```